# Tortoise svn client hook script from command line

Tags: svn, c#-4.0, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

Do you know if there exist a command to create a client hook script for TortoiseSVN? I need to create the hook from C# code, not from GUI.

I looked for command at the [following page](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-automation.html), but there is no information about hook scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client-side hook scripts are [documented in the TSVN manual](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks).

They must be configured on each client, and can't be "forced" from the repository server.

Comment: Hi @alroc I've read that. That's where I see hook scripts first, while looking for a different thing. But what I would like to know, and I should have explained better, is if there is a way to attach hook scripts without user interaction. I mean: may be append text to some file where Tortoise is saving the hook script list???

Comment: Have a look at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\TortoiseSVN` for a string named hooks (it may not be there if you haven't previously configured one). This sounds like a potential security attack vector though, so be cautious. To find documentation on how it needs to be formatted, you'll have to check the TSVN sources.

Comment: Thanks alroc, I'll be checking this method, and hope to be back with results

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you will NOT be able to script into Tortoise SVN like that.

Tortoise does have some hooks that you can set in the interface which are different from server-side SVN hooks.